# repacked system image fails to boot

Tags: builds, aosp

I have a problem where the repacked system.img does not work.

My target device is: DOOGEE X5pro, which uses MT6735M chip.

I am using [this](http://www.needrom.com/download/r16-android-6-0/) custom ROM.

The original files from this custom ROM works fine with the device.

I wanted to change something in the system.img and the following is what I did.

```
$ simg2img system.img system.raw
$ mkdir tempsys
$ sudo mount -t ext4 -o loop system.raw tempsys
$ cd tempsys
```

Here I made one change. I didn't like the camera shutter sound so I simply deleted the 'camer_shutter.ogg' file in `tempsys/media/audio/ui`.

```
$ cd ..
$ tune2fs -l system.raw
```

here I check that "Block count : 390111", "Block size: 4096". I multiplied these two values and got "1,597,894,656".

```
$ sudo make_ext4 -a system -l 1597894656 -s sys3.img tempsys
```

BTW the permission of the sys3.img is as below:

```
$ ls -l
-rw-r--r--   1 chadrick chadrick 1327287648  2월 18 16:09 sys3.img
```

I'm not sure if the permission of the system.img file matters before flashing it to the phone.

I shall proceed just as it is.

After flashing it, it is stuck at the boot logo. I guess while the device succeeded upto loading the 'boot.img' but it failed to properly deal with 'system.img'.

Apparently, could someone point out some things that I may have missed?

BTW, I did the same repack operation WITHOUT modifying any contents in with system.raw file. The repacked system.img still didn't work.

Comment: Doubts: permission fault *inside* the repacked image. Are you able to obtain a logcat, or does it not even proceed to bootanimation?

Comment: @Andy Yan It doesn't even proceed to the bootanimation. I haven't tried the logcat method. But I have tried `adb device` to see if I can get the adb shell. However, it was described as `unauthorized` and `adb shell` didn't work.

Comment: Yeah that definitely means logcat isn't possible. I don't have more ideas; wait for someone else..

Comment: If you wanted to turn off shutter sound you could rename it from file manager if you have root, maybe even don't need root.

Comment: Do you have a custom recovery, OP?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman custom recovery? not exactly sure what you are saying. But I haven't touched anything near the recovery.img in the custom rom files.

Comment: @kwagjj Can you check if the flashing procedure did actually write anything in the /system partition?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman I use the SP Flash tool in order to flash the images to the partitions. Whenever I flash it with the original system.img file, the phone boots up fine. Whenever I flash it with the modfiied system.img file, the boot is stuck on the logo. From this symptom, I thought that the 'flashing' is totally okay.

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје thanks for the suggestion. But my main quest is trying to find out why my custom packed system.img doesn't work.